# How to use <a href=""> to ADD to current url

Tags: html, hyperlink, shopify, href

I am working on a Shopify store, and we have an issue. Ultimately, people are being sent to a URL that looks like this:

www.store.com/collections/[collectionname]

On this page, we are looking to make a new HREF's. Ultimately, I want this HREF to be like:
www.store.com/collections/[collectionname]/MYLINK

How do I make a  simply add to the current URL?

Thanks!

Comment: For now add # only, while doing backend, the link will be added accordingly.

Comment: Sorry? I don't understand. If I use #mylink, it just refers to www.store.com/collections/[collectionname]#mylink

Answer (score 0):

This path is predefined to filter collections by tag. So considering the path `/collections/cars/autopilot` will try to load the `Cars` collection and filter products by `autopilot` tag. There's no way to override that. But you can use the `current_tags` global variable on the collection page to detect by which tag the collection is currently filtered by and use that information to change the content, behaviour or whatever you wanted it for.